# Obtaining a URL up to the context path from the current HTTP request in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Assuming the following URL (with or without any query-string and/or extra path info).

`https://localhost:8181/ContextPath/xxx/page.xhtml`

Which I need to extract the following portion from.

`https://localhost:8181/ContextPath`

i.e. up to the context path.

---

This can be done in one way defining a utility method of our interest something along the following piece of code.

```
public static String getBaseURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    return new String(url.substring(0, url.length() - request.getRequestURI().length())) + request.getContextPath();
}
```

And it can be invoked from managed beans as follows.

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String link=Utility.getBaseURL(request);
```

But this in turn requires exposing the underlying `javax.servlet.*` API which I am not interested in.

Is there a sane JSF way in which the said portion of a URL from the current HTTP request can be obtained without explicitly exposing the underlying Servlet API?

---

<sup>I am not interested in individually collecting portions like scheme, server name, port, context path etc. using their respective separate methods associated with an instance of `HttpServletRequest`.</sup>

Comment: No there isn't. You can't get it without an `HttpServletRequest` instance. Unfortunately

Comment: What do you actually need this *for?*

Comment: Doesn't exist @Tiny. There's no single, magic method (within JSF) that returns all that. A lot of that information is built on the way into the container. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()` to your utility methdod and the `javax.servlet.*` API is NOT exposed...

Comment: `FacesContext` (or `ExternalContext`) should not be passed outside the JSF context - in a plain utility Java  class  where the `getBaseURL()` method is situated (`Utility` in this case). Actually I am also not interested in passing an instance of  `HttpServletRequest` itself but that's what I have just presented as an example. Thank you.

Comment: Then create a JSFUtility that wrappes this?

Comment: I do not have an idea about it. Otherwise, I would not have asked the question itself :). I assumed that methods like `request.getRequestURL()` and `request.getRequestURI()` might have been provided/wrapped by `ExternalContext` or something else.

Comment: :-). Maybe I react to simple, but even OmniFaces does not have a solution for this and I myself do not see using the servlet api as a problem